# Why does this ng-model variable not work?

Tags: angularjs, variables

So I'm trying to create a program in Angular for displaying train schedules.  Here's my question, why does the "firstTT" variable break the program?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app = "myApp" ng-controller = "myCtrl">

<table>
  <tr><th>Train Name</th><th>Destination</th><th>Frequency</th><th>Minutes Away</th><th>Next Arrival</th><th></th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in trainArray">
    <td>{{ x.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.dest }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.freq }}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>X</td>
  </tr>
</table>
{{dayMinutes}}

<form>
 Train Name: <input type = "text"  ng-model = "name"/> 
 <br>
 <br>
Destination: <input type = text" ng-model = "dest"/>
<br>
<br>
First Train Time: <input type="text" placeholder = "(ex. 08:45 for 8:45pm)" ng-model = "firstTT">
<br>
<br>
Frequency (Minutes): <input type="text" style = "width: 50px;" ng-model = "freq">
<br>
<br>
<input type = "submit" value = "submit" id = "submit" data-toggle = "tool-tip" title = "add train">
</form>
</div>
<script>
 var dayMillis = moment().diff(moment().startOf('day'));
  
  //minutes since start of day
 var dayMinutes = dayMillis/60000;

//why the hell does it say this is "not defined" and break the program?
// console.log(firstTT);
//regardless, I need to get the diff between this and the start of the day.
//that should look something like this:
// var startMinutes = moment(firstTT, "hh:mm").diff(moment().startOf('day'));
 
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.firstTT = "";
    $scope.dayMinutes = dayMinutes;
      $scope.trainArray = [
      {
          name: "Thomas",
  dest: "New York",
  first: "05:00",
  freq: 30
      },
      {
           name: "Duncan",
  dest: "Boston",
  first: "06:00",
  freq: 45
      }]
  })
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

It claims the variable is undefined, and that causes all the AngularJS to cease to function.  I tried adding the "init" and the "$scope", but that didn't work.  What's the deal?

Answer (score 0):

The variable `firstTT` is indeed undefined, you never declare it. It seems that you are expecting `firstTT` to be the value of the input field where you have declared `ng-model="firstTT"`. In angularjs the model part of the model-view-controller is a `$scope`, this means that `ng-model="firstTT"` binds to `$scope.firstTT` which can only be accessed in your controller implementation.

My guess is that you would like to calculate `startMinutes` when the value in the input field changes, to do this you need to do a couple of things.

First implement a method which can be called when the input value changes, you must do this on the `$scope` so that you can bind the method in the view.

```
$scope.onFirstTrainTimeChange = function() {
    var startMinutes = moment($scope.firstTT, "hh:mm").diff(moment().startOf('day'));
};
```

Then use the `ng-change` directive on your input field to call the method above when the input changes.

```
<input ... ng-model="firstTT" ng-change="onFirstTrainTimeChange()">
```

You may also want to do other things, like handle errors when the input is not in the correct format, and use the `ng-model-options` directive to control when the model gets updated (e.g. debounce) so that the method isn't called until the user stops making changes to the input field.